# Laravel blade, adding slashes to date variable

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a laravel blade template that is displaying a date as long as the variable for the date isn't null. This is working but it's only displaying 8 digits together, no hyphens or slashes.

Here is the html of the blade:

```
@if ($psku->avail_date)
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: 700;">Available Date:</td>
  <td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ $psku->avail_date }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endif
```

What's the best way to alter that variable `{{ $psku->avail_date }}` to show slashes like this '12/34/5678'

Comment: If avail_date is Carbon you can do `$psku->avail_date->format(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If psku is an instance of your model and `avail_date` is defined as a date within the model, Laravel will return an instance of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon).

You can format your string directly by using e.g.

```
<td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ $psku->avail_date->toDateString() }}</td>
```

See http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

If your Date is a String, you can create a Carbon instance and then use the formatting options

```
<td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::create(C$psku->avail_date)->toDateString() }}
```

Comment: To define the ``avail_date`` as a Carbon instance in the model, make sure it set as a date mutator [as shown here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Comment: Carbon is a date formatter in PHP. I believe it comes included in Laravel by default. Just try it.

Comment: Sorry, I actually used the second suggestion and it works but it shows today's date. This variable actually shows different dates from the database. I just want to add the formatting

Comment: @matthiass I tried this ```{{  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($psku->avail_date)->format('d/m/Y') }}``` but I get an error of parsing string at position 7 and it's and 8 digit date.

Comment: Could you provide the format of your 8 digit date? Like, post an example? Then I'll look into it and edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the following syntax and you will get the formatting you are looking for.

```
{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($psku->avail_date))}}
```